# Two arrays combine into {array1[i], array2[i]} without double for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays: arrayOfIds and arrayOfScores. I need to map corresponding id to score (1on1 map), finally I should have array of {id_i, score_i} items. First id from arrayOfIds to first score from arrayOfScores. Is there better way to do that than using double for loop? Both arrays have same length of course.

Example:

```
var arrayOfIds = ['4', '6', '8', '10', '12'];
var arrayOfScores= [0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7];
```

Result:

```
var combined = [ {id: '4', score: 0.1}, 
                 {id: '6', score: 0.5}, 
                 {id: '8', score: 0.8}, 
                 {id: '10', score: 0.3}, 
                 {id: '12', score: 0.7}
               ];
```

Comment: To help your thinking : why would you need a 'double' for loop? If they're the same length, you can just use one loop and use the same iteration variable for both arrays.

Comment: Why two loops? One is enough. Or `Array.reduce()` or `Array.map()` or `Array.forEach()`

Comment: @KarlReid I imagine the asker meant in series, not nested for loops. For a beginner, this is an understandable conceptual misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

You could just map one of the arrays, and use the index to fetch data from the other array, as long as they are the same length

```js
var arrayOfIds    = ['4', '6', '8', '10', '12'];
var arrayOfScores = [0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7];

var combined = arrayOfIds.map( (x,i) => ({id : x, score : arrayOfScores[i]}));

console.log(combined)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd need a double for loop for this. Even with a `for` loop, you only need one. Just use the same index on both arrays.

```js
var arrayOfIds = ['4', '6', '8', '10', '12'];
var arrayOfScores = [0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7];
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfIds.length; i++) {
  result.push({
    id: arrayOfIds[i],
    score: arrayOfScores[i]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

This assumes the lengths are the same. If not, you'll need to adjust for that.

Any other looping construct available could be used in like manner. The idea is to access both arrays in each iteration. So here's an example using `for of` instead with some other modern features.

```js
var arrayOfIds = ['4', '6', '8', '10', '12'];
var arrayOfScores = [0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7];
var result = [];
for (const [i, id] of arrayOfIds.entries()) {
  result[i] = {
    id,
    score: arrayOfScores[i]
  };
}

console.log(result);
```

And here's one using `Array.from`:

```js
var arrayOfIds = ['4', '6', '8', '10', '12'];
var arrayOfScores = [0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7];
var result = Array.from(arrayOfIds, (id, i) => ({id, score: arrayOfScores[i]}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it short using [lodash `_.zip`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zip) and some ES6 arrow functions, array destructuring and shorthand object properties.

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3];
const scores = [1100, 1000, 900];

const result = _.zip(ids, scores).map(([id,score]) => ({id, score}));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```